# How can you upload XSD into an Azure Integration Account as part of an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

How can you upload XSD into an Azure Integration Account to use in a Logic App, as part of an Azure DevOps pipeline?

I've read the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-schemas#add-schemas) on how to add an xsd on Microsoft doc's, but this is a manual process.

How can I do this in the pipelines (as well as update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PowerShell and the Az cmdlets ...

```
New-AzIntegrationAccountSchema `
        -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
        -Name $IntegrationAccountName `
        -SchemaName $SchemaName `
        -SchemaFilePath $SchemaFilePath
```

Comment: `$SchemaFilePath` ? so now your pipeline is dependent on a schema being present in that file path?  *how do we 'load' a file within the pipeline and just populate some powershell variable and pass in the schema in memory rather than a link to it?*

Comment: @AlexGordon You need to store the file in some blob storage, ensure your pipeline has access to it & then run the script

Answer (score 1):

I've uploaded an XSD schema via Portal while having DevTools (F12) open to find out which Azure REST API endpoint the Portal was making a call to create the schema in my Integration Account.

Based on that, It looks like you can make a call to the following endpoint in your DevOps pipeline to create schema in your Integration Account: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/schemas/createorupdate

Hope this helps!

Comment: how do we load the schema from our source repo?